# Get realtime page notifications facebook

Tags: facebook

I need to get page notifications(new comments, new likes, new post likes etc.). Is there any solution that I can make it realtime?

Realtime api doesn't support it.
FQL doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime API does not support it, however **FQL does support it**. Given a URL, you can always get comments and likes using `comment` and `link_stat` tables.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time
FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN (
   SELECT comments_fbid
   FROM link_stat
   WHERE url ='http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/')
```

`link_stat` table has `comment_count`, `like_count` etc as well. You have *poll* for this content, as you will *not get realtime* notifications.